# Determine which particles are visible on an opaque object from current camera position

Tags: python, particles

I have an object with a particle system (hairs).
I'd like to work with the hair's point location on the surface of a mesh to do stuff. 
Suffice to say, I only want to work with the visible hairs, so that I don't have to deal with the hairs on the other side of the mesh, which are not visible.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import bpy
import mathutils

from mathutils import Vector
from mathutils.bvhtree import BVHTree
from bpy_extras.object_utils import world_to_camera_view

# Get context elements: scene, camera and opaque  object.
scene = bpy.context.scene
cam = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']

# Create a BVH tree and return bvh, particle locations.
def BVHTreeAndParticlesInWorldFromObj( obj ):
    particleLocations = [p.location for p in obj.particle_systems[0].particles]
    bvh = BVHTree.FromObject(bpy.data.objects['Cube'], scene, deform=True, render=False, cage=False, epsilon=0.)
    return bvh, particleLocations

# Threshold to test if ray cast corresponds to the original particle location.
limit = 0.0001

# Get a bvh tree for opaque object and particle locations
bvh, particleLocations = BVHTreeAndParticlesInWorldFromObj( obj )

for i, p in enumerate( particleLocations ):

    # Try a ray cast, in order to test the vertex visibility from the camera
    direction = Vector(p) - Vector(cam.location)
    location, normal, index, distance = bvh.ray_cast( cam.location, direction )

    if location and (p - location).length < limit:
        print ('This is a visible particle.')

del bvh
```

Now this isn't working and I cannot figure out why? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!